# Why won't `this.$axios.$get(...)` work in nuxt.js store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I've started working with `nuxt.js` after using `vue` for quite a while but even after following nuxt.js documentation on [vuex](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/) and [axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage.html), I don't understand why `this.$axios.$get(...)` won't work. This is what I have

```
/* ~/store/products.js */

export const state = () => ({
  products: []
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
    state.products = products
  }
}

export const actions = {
  getProducts({ commit }) {
    this.$axios.$get("merchandise.json").then(res => {
      commit("SET_PRODUCTS", res)
    })
  }
}

export const getters = {}
```

```
/* ~/pages/index.vue */
...
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from "vuex"
import Card from "@/components/Card.vue"

export default {
  components: {
    Card
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([ "getProducts" ])
  },
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.state.products.products
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is how my configuration looks like

```
/* nuxt.config.js */

...
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv",
    ...
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
...
```

```
/* .env */

BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000/data/
```

If I do `this.$axios.$get("merchandise.json")` in other files like in `~/pages/index.vue` it works but doesn't work in the store. What could be the problem?

Comment: What means "doesnt work"? Check your browser debug network tab to see what it does.

Comment: I can't find any issues in the network tab. Everything is loading just fine.

Comment: this.$axios should be used inside Vue component. A store is decoupled from components.

Comment: @EstusFlask I followed [this example](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage.html#store-actions) from the docs

Comment: @Emmanuel where do you call the store action? this is not shown in your example.

Comment: @4ern I've tried using both `...mapActions([ 'getProducts ]) ` and `this.$store.dispatch('getProducts)` but still not working. I've edited the question

Comment: @Emmanuel nuxt use vuex in modules mode. therefore you have to include the namespace  `this.$store.dispatch('products/getProducts)`

Comment: @4ern Thanks, that worked perfectly. What if I need to call or define many actions at once. Can I do this `...mapActions([ "products/getProducts" ])` ?

Comment: No, but you can add all your actions in a vue mixin. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html